# uploading simle asp.net website to appharbor from codeplex

Tags: asp.net, .net, build, appharbor, codeplex

I have create a new test asp.net web application project on [codeplex](https://haseeb1431.codeplex.com) to upload files onto my [appharbor domain](http://haseeb1431.apphb.com/). but build is getting failed

I am currently focusing on to fix first issue

> The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Web'

I have installed the Optimaztion package.  I can see the dll in the reference. I set the `copylocal` to `true` in the dll properties. but still getting the same error

a view of Build log is as follows

```
       "D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjectFiles.sln" (default target) (1) ->
       "D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
       (CoreCompile target) -> 
         App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(5,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         App_Start\AuthConfig.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         Account\Manage.aspx.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         Account\OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs(4,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         Account\Register.aspx.cs(8,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         Account\RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DotNetOpenAuth' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         Account\RegisterExternalLogin.aspx.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         App_Start\RouteConfig.cs(5,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         Global.asax.cs(5,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         ViewSwitcher.ascx.cs(8,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(12,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         Account\Manage.aspx.cs(71,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OpenAuthAccountData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]
         Account\OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs(37,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ProviderDetails' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\temp\qruzvbcw.ri3\input\MyProjects\MyProjects.csproj]

    18 Warning(s)
    13 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.62
```

What else I can do

I am unable to see the bin folder in my [codeplex project source](https://haseeb1431.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the Codeplex repository it seems like you haven't added the NuGet packages required by your application. Either add the packages to your repository, or consider using [NuGet package restore](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/06/use-nuget-package-restore-to-avoid-pushing-packages-to-appharbor) to automatically fetch the packages when the application is build.

Answer (score 0):

My project: VS 2012 Web Express MVC 4, Bootstrap Layout, Version Control TFS.

I added the account controller, model and related views after the functionality of the site was completed. Many of the references / packages were missing. I was able to ad some of them via Nuget however what fixed the last few pesky errors was right clicking on the solution in solution explorer and updating Nuget packages.

I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough rep points.